# Camera Jitters Matrix Camera

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, velocity, perspectivecamera

I am using a translation matrix to move the screen but when the player collides with an object the player will jitter as if it wants to be in 2 places at once. It looks like velocity wants to keep going down while the block pushes it up, how would I go by fixing this?

Video: [Here](http://youtu.be/EkZQAOvKQgE)

Camera class:

```
class Camera
{
    public Vector2 Position;
    Viewport viewPort;
    public Vector2 cameraBounds;

    public float wasGround;

    public Matrix Transform()
    {
        var translationMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0));

        return translationMatrix;
    }

    public Player thing(Player player)
    {
        cameraBounds.X = player.Position.X - Game1.offset.X;
        if (cameraBounds.X > 0)
            Position.X = player.Position.X - Game1.offset.X;
        else
            Position.X = 0;

        //Problem      
        cameraBounds.Y = player.Position.Y - Game1.offset.Y;
        if (cameraBounds.Y > 0)
        {
            Position.Y = player.Position.Y - Game1.offset.Y;

            if (player.goingUp == false && (wasGround != player.ground))
                Position.Y = player.ground - Game1.offset.Y;

            wasGround = player.ground;
        }
        else
            Position.Y = 0;


        return player;
    }

    public Camera(Viewport viewport)
    {
        viewPort = viewport;
    }
}
```

I tried to fix the problem by adding in player goingUp and ground if statements but that did not help.

Comment: If you can share the project I will 100% solve this solution. xD

Comment: @Wallstrider I will test if Davor has given me the correct answer then I will try and link the whole project. If you have any ideas on how I would do so that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes because I don't know how you actually handling the collisions. The only camera is not enough for me.

Comment: How do I show all of the code? What is the web site I should put it on? Should I make a zip of it and put it somewhere and link to it?

Comment: You can use [this site](https://onedrive.live.com/) to upload an archive with your solution. After I download it you can delete the link if you don't want someone stole your project. I won't because I have already done with my 2D game.

Comment: Here is the link [Here](https://mega.co.nz/#!68hQHQzD!G3MSCN9tmcVL-Dh7EsgWBWmYDiQM8lTq6V5bGIxkeQs) Hopefully you can look this over. All I wanted was this jittering fixed and it would be great. Thank you Wallstrider.

Comment: Ok, I will post new answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It is about sequence of operations. Just move method camera.thing() as shown below:

```
            // TODO: Add your update logic here
        HandleInput(Keyboard.GetState());
        player.Update(gameTime);
        // delete from here
        Time += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        foreach (Block b in Blocks)
        {
            player = b.BlockCollision(player);
        }
        // place here
        camera.thing(player);
```

Explanation: You have to set camera position after all collisions have done.

Comment: I love you, thank you for the help. I should have see that haha.

Answer (score 0):

what i can see while you stand still on some object, velocity changes. so try to convert camera position to integer. or make velocity exact 0 if is near 0.

```
 cameraBounds.X = cInt(cameraBounds.X)
 cameraBounds.y = cInt(cameraBounds.y)
```

Comment: If I make velocity exactly 0 when near it, it will never change, how do I make the player know it is on top of an object and in air? When the player collides with the object it sets velocity to 0, but every frame it will increase the velocity to check if it is on an object, if the player is on an object the player velocity will be set to 0 if not the velocity will increase.

Comment: set some flag IsCollided to true when collision happened, and set it back to false when you move character.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, sorry that your answer was not selected. But Wallstrider had an easier fix than your method.